# Live Streaming Issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement, live-streaming, windows-media-services

I am developing an app to view live channels. Channels are hosted on `Windows Media Services 9`. I am using `MediaElement` for playing the stream and it is playing the stream first time but doesnt play on second attempt unless i relaunch the app.

Same problem with internet explorer on WP7 it plays the stream first time but not on second attempt.

Is it a bug? or is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS Smooth Streaming? If not, why not? Considering you're developing for a mobile device that would need to scale to unknown network conditions adaptive streaming would be better than progressive download playback.

If you are using IIS Smooth Streaming on the server side, you shouldn't use < MediaElement Source="http://foo" /> but rather use the < ssme:SmoothStreamingMediaElement StreamSource="http://foo/bar.ism/manifest" /> control.

There's a lot of documentation out there on [setting up an IIS smooth streaming endpoint](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/558/getting-started-with-iis-smooth-streaming) and [consuming it from WP7](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/09/29/using-smooth-streaming-video-client-in-windows-phone-7/). You should also consider using the [< smf:SmfPlayer />](http://smf.codeplex.com/) control as it gives you a fully-featured WP7 video player and not just a playback rectangle like the mediaelements do.

Comment: we used `SSME` but it has very low sound however, `MediaElement` has better sound quality but it doesn't play channel at second attempt.

Comment: Ha? SSME has nothing to do with audio quality AFAIK. It's all about your IIS Smooth Streaming server encoding settings. Tinker around with the audio encoding settings until you're happy with it.